# exception occurring in chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, code,callback)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm learning `chrome extension development` and I'm trying to get the required tabs using `chrome.tabs.query`. Inside that I'm executing a script and passing a `callback` function, but when code reaches the callback it throws an exception, see below:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true , currentWindow: true,lastFocusedWindow: true}, function(tabs)
{  
console.log(tabs);
var tab = tabs[0];
console.log(tab);
var check_url = tab.url
console.log(check_url);
var check_importers = check_url.split("/");
console.log(check_importers);
try {
console.log("line 111");

        if(check_importers[3].includes("tbm=lcl"))
        {
        console.log("line 122")
                       
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {     
        code: console.log("Hello world")
        },passDetails);
                        
    
        }
        else
        {
        console.log("line 199");
        console.log("Search Importers of Spices");
        }
        }//try end
        catch (err)
        {
        console.log("URL not found")
        }

}
```

This is what I tried by following documentation and blogs I found.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What error message exactly? Just from a quick glance, in your `executeScript`  the `code` property contains `undefined` because you are executing console.log right the way and attaching it's return (which is `undefined`) to the `code` property. Another questionable is what's in `passDetails` variable? Also you are missing closing `)` at the end. Oh and finally, when you use `try...catch(err)` output information from `err` not just your "url not found"

Comment: I resolved the issue...I was using tabs api but we have to use scripting api as per manifest v3...thank you everyone for the response